# Splitting a Cube

Tags: geometry

Choosing two random points on a segment will split it into 3 smaller segments. Similarly, choosing three random points on a square will define three lines which split the square into seven sections. Into how may sections will a cube be split when four random points are chosen, thereby defining four intersecting planes? Can this be generalized to higher dimensions?

Comment: Four intersecting planes define a tetrahedron, so for the cube it would be fifteen: one section is the interior of the tetrahedron; four sections adjoin its four faces; six sections adjoin its six edges without adjoining any faces; and four sections adjoin its four vertices without adjoining any edges.

Comment: Note that for this to work the 3 points in the square cannot lie on a line. Otherwise, you get degenerate regions of zero size. Similarly, the 4 points in the cube cannot all be in the same plane, and no 3 of those points can lie on the same line. Etc.

Comment: @PM 2Ring If the points are randomly chosen, this shouldn't occur

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$3, 7, 15, 31, ...$

Every hyperplane divides the space in half and thus splits every region it touches in half; however, after $n$ hyperplanes are placed in an $n$-dimensional space, the intersection of these hyperplanes is a single point.  At this point you've got $2^n$ regions.  The final, $n+1$th hyperplane can't go through that point (without missing even more regions), so it can only go through at most $2^n-1$ regions and split those.

$n+1$ hyperplanes can split an $n$-dimensional space into $2^{n+1}-1$ regions.